# empty list response extract on scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm new on scrapy and i have to crawl a webpage for a test. So I use the code below on a terminal but its returns a empty list i Don't understand why. When i use the same command on a another website, like amazon, with the right selector, it works. Can someone put light on it? thank you so much

```py
scrapy shell "'https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas"

response.css('.tileList-title').extract()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when I consulted the source code of the page you seemed interested to **scrape** the title `Iced Teas` in a header tags `<h1>`. Am I right ?

Second, I tried  scrapy shell sessions to understand the issue. It seems to be a settings of user-agent request's headers. Look at the code sessions below:

**Without user-agent set**

```
scrapy shell https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas
In [1]: response.css('.tileList-title').extract()                               
Out[1]: []
view(response) #open the given response in your local web browser, for inspection.
```

[image: screenshot without user-agent]

**With user agent set**

```
scrapy shell https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'

In [1]: response.css('.tileList-title').extract()                               
Out[1]: ['<h1 class="tileList-title" ng-if="$ctrl.listTitle" tabindex="-1">Iced Teas</h1>']
#now as you can see it does not return an empty list.
view(response)
```

### [image: screenshot with user-agent]

So to improve your future practices, know you can use `-s KEYWORDSETTING=value` in your scrapy shell sessions. Here the [settings key words](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html) for scrapy.
And to check with `view(response)` to see if the requests returns the expected content even if it sent a 200. For my experience, with `view(response)` you can see that the content page, and even source code sometimes, is a little different when you use it in scrapy shell than when you use it in a normal browser. So that's a good practice to check with this shortcut. Here the [shorcuts](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#available-shortcuts) for scrapy. They are mentioned at each scrapy shell session too.