# Find the right selector css to crawl a webpage on scrapy

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to crawl this webpage "https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas" to extract the products name but I can't find the right selector, even for the price, h1 or the title! I tried :

```py
response.css(".shelfProductTile-descriptionLink") #for the name product
response.css(".price-cents") # for the price
response.css(".tileList-title") # for the title
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: That data is coming from a XHR. Most modern websites do something similar.

Comment: As I told you in your [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57807415/empty-list-response-extract-on-scrapy) if you use the right user agent you will obtain a list of selectors. Now I am more comfortable with xpath selectors, so I cannot help you with css selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is dynamically loaded from a POST xhr returning json you can find in network tab of browser.

Request goes to:

```
https://www.woolworths.com.au/apis/ui/browse/category
```

Payload:

```
{"categoryId":"1_9573995","pageNumber":1,"pageSize":24,"sortType":"TraderRelevance","url":"/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas","location":"/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas","formatObject":"{\"name\":\"Iced Teas\"}","isSpecial":False,"isBundle":False,"isMobile":False,"filters":"null"}
```

with response in scrapy use:

```
json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your instructions. Can you tell more how did you do it please ?